# Why can't I use inspect.getsource() to view the source for list?

Tags: python, list, introspection, python-internals

I tried to retrieve the source code for the `list` class using the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) module, without success:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getsource(list)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 701, in getsource
    lines, lnum = getsourcelines(object)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 690, in getsourcelines
    lines, lnum = findsource(object)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 526, in findsource
    file = getfile(object)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 408, in getfile
    raise TypeError('{!r} is a built-in class'.format(object))
TypeError: <module '__builtin__' (built-in)> is a built-in class
```

I don't understand why this didn't work - [the documentation for `inspect.getsource()`](https://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsource) says that

> An IOError is raised if the source code cannot be retrieved.

... but doesn't explain why that might happen (and in any case I got a `TypeError`, not an `IOError`).

Is there some other way I can programmatically retrieve the source for an object in cases like this? If not, how can I find the source for myself?

Comment: try here: https://www.python.org/downloads/source/

Comment: List, like all the built-in types, is implemented in C, so you can't get the code via introspection.

Comment: [I believe this is what you need](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L130)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While [`inspect.getsource()`](https://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsource) can retrieve the source code for objects written in Python, `list` is written in C, so there's no Python source for `getsource()` to retrieve.

If you're comfortable reading C, you can find the complete source code for Python at its [official GitHub repo](https://github.com/python/cpython). For example, the source of `list` for various releases can be found at:

- https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c (latest development version)
- https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/listobject.c
- https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/listobject.c

... and so on.